# Using tynamo ckeditor in tapestry

Tags: tapestry, tynamo

I'm newbie in Tapestry. I'm trying to use Tynamo CKEditor to make wysiwyg-editor on a page. There is a [guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/TYNAMO/tapestry-ckeditor+guide). Maven installed it. Firstly, I tried to copy code from this page, but it didn't work (there was a error of the page's deploying). I modified code. As a result I can see the page, but CKEditor still doesn't work.

About.tml:

```
 <t:form>
    <t:textarea t:id="textarea" t:value="contents" t:mixins="tynamo/ckeditor" parameters="{'toolbar': 'Full'}" />
</t:form>
```

About.java:

```
package com.schoolmath.costructor.pages;

import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property;

public class About
{
    @Property
    private String contents;
}
```

A screenshot of the error:
http://cs418327.vk.me/v418327411/a53d/1py6ea7BNKc.jpg

Comment: Are you also using security? See if you actually receive all the requested resources.